# Spring Thymeleaf for each last not woking

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am iterating over a MongoDB document.

where data is FindIterable.

```
<tr th:each="document, state : ${data}">
  <td th:text="${state.count}"></td>
</tr>
```

state.last not working on iterable? why?

Instead of `state.count` if i use `state.first` it prints true for first element and false for all the rest.

When I use `state.last` it throws an exception.

Why can't I use `state.last` in this way?

Here is the Exception I got.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "state.count + ' ' + state.last"
at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:165) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:126) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: What's the exception trace?

Comment: Reworded to make it clearer

Comment: Not enough details... we need the exception.  `${state.last}` is the correct expression, and I just tested that it works.

Comment: I have updated my question and add the Exception error

Comment: I couldn't replicate, works for me. Though note that you have got one `</td>`-tag too much.

Comment: It was a typo when i copy snippet to stackover flow. can not make that code work not sure why its not working

Comment: I have updated my question can you please review and help me with this now.

Comment: Your exception indicates that there is a concat "state.count + ' ' + state.last". I don't see the coresponding template-snippet. You could give the following expression a try: th:text="|${state.count} ${state.last}|"

Comment: Still same error it seem state.last not worked with iterator.

Comment: Another idea is, that there is no last-property or that there is only a last-property if it's value is true (ok, that would be stuppied). You could test this with:  th:text="${state.count == state.index + 1 ? state.last : 'something else'}".

Comment: There is another problem with state.count it returns index instead of count for iterable.

Comment: 3.0.9 is the latest version. Are you forcing that version or comes 3.0.9 with spring boot 2.0.2 (I actually don't know) ?

Comment: I dont know i am using spring boot 2.0.0.RELEASE